# how to authenticate a login on the server with angular and node.js

Tags: angular, http, get

I'm having trouble authenticating a login on the server via node.js and angular. I don't even know where to begin.

I returned the input(login) data and saved it in an array named user. I then tried(what I think) to pass that user array to my service.ts file to get the authentication return.

```
//service.ts:

loginUser(user): any {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/login',user);
}

//login.component.ts:

onLogin() {

const user = {

  username: this.userName,
  password: this.password,
};

this.loginService.loginUser(user).subscribe(data => {

  console.log(data);


}
);
```

Comment: the problem is not clear here. are you saying server is not responding as expected? or how to verify in `loginUser(user).subscribe` whether user login was successful or not?

Comment: Redux would be great to implement this along with localstorage. Complete example: https://mherman.org/blog/authentication-in-angular-with-ngrx/

Comment: I’m getting the full list of users when I log the “data” to the console. Rather than the single user